# Set the actor of a reaction in GetStream

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, getstream-io

I'm using Google Firebase Cloud Functions to add a reaction to my Stream activity when a user comments.

The docs say you add a reaction this way:

```
let comment = await client.reactions.add("comment", activityId, {"text": "awesome post!"});
```

But I can't see here how to set the actor of the reaction, i.e. the person writing the comment.

I see from the docs that I can set a target feed, i.e. the author of the original post or someone mentioned in the comment, but again, this doesn't set the person writing the comment:

```
client.reactions.add("comment", activityId, 
    {"text": "@thierry great post!"},
   {targetFeeds:  ["notification:thierry"]}
);
```

N.B. This isn't in the client, but rather a serverless function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use reactions server-side you must include the user_id as well when you call reactions.add

This is the signature of `reactions.add`

```
  add: function(
    kind,
    activity,
    data = {},
    { id, targetFeeds = [], userId, targetFeedsExtraData } = {},
    callback,
  )
```